# Windows Program to Graphically Display Traceroute

Tags: windows, networking

Is there a windows program that allows you to visualize a traceroute on a geographic map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Visual Trace Route](http://visualroute.visualware.com/) is my go to utility for this.

Answer (score 3):

[PingPlotter](http://www.pingplotter.com/) comes to mind.

Comment: +1 vary handy tool, however, it doesn't appear to give you the ability to overlay the data on a geographic map.

Comment: Sorry. Missed that point in your question.